# Variable URL for a simple Volley string request

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I'm creating a simple database using the volley library. im having problems selecting which specific database to send it to. Before I explain what my specific problem is here is the code:

```
package com.example.joker.sqltrial;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/*  *
 * Created by Joker on 2016-12-13.
 */

public class PostRequest extends StringRequest {


    private static String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL="";
    private Map<String, String> params;



    public PostRequest(String animal, int sizeClass, String spType, String          description, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super (Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("animal", animal);
        params.put("size class", sizeClass+"");
        params.put("specie type", spType);
        params.put("description", description);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {

        return params;
    }

    public static void urlSet(String URL){
        REGISTER_REQUEST_URL=URL;
    }
}
```

so in this line of code "super (Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);", im providing a URL thats supposed to be a Final String...i would like to change that URL(the table/database) which it would go to, depending on what the user enters. in another class i have the URL selected, dependent on what is chosen from a spinner, and then that url is passed throw another method which passed it to this class using an object. here is the code for the other class

```
   btButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final String animal = etAnimal.getText().toString();
                final String sizeClass = etsizeClass.getText().toString();
                final int spType  = Integer.parseInt(etspType.getText().toString());
                final int blaha = Integer.parseInt(etBlah.getText().toString());
                final String blahBlah = etBlahBlah.getText().toString();


                switch (category) {
                    case "human":
                        tempURL ="SOME SPECIFIC URL";
                        setURL(tempURL);
                        break;
                    case "alien":
                        tempURL ="SOME SPECIFIC URL";
                        setURL(tempURL);
                        break;
                    case "animal":
                        tempURL ="SOME SPECIFIC URL";
                        setURL(tempURL);
                        break;
                    default:
                        tempURL=null;
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "try again and input correct characters", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                            if (success){
                                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewAd.class);
                                MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);
                            }
                            else{
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Posting failed!")
                                        .setNegativeButton("retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                };


                PostRequest postRequest = new PostRequest(animal, sizeClass, spType, description, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                queue.add(postRequest);
            }
        });
    }


    public void setURL(String URL){
        tempURL=URL;
        PostRequest.urlSet(URL);


    }
```

...so essentially when the button is clicked, the response listener would see what was picked from the spinner and then depending on that pass on a specific URL which would set the URL in the other class before it is even called upon...what am i doing wrong? i know its a simple solution i cant figure it out. Please can somebody help me out? thank you.

and this is the stack trace i got:

```
01-19 21:06:20.300 221-542/? W/genymotion_audio: out_write() limiting sleep time 46802 to 39909
01-19 21:06:20.596 1514-1514/com.example.joker.sqltrial W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-19 21:06:20.596 1514-1514/com.example.joker.sqltrial W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
01-19 21:06:20.596 1514-1514/com.example.joker.sqltrial W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
01-19 21:06:20.596 1514-1514/com.example.joker.sqltrial W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
01-19 21:06:20.596 1514-1514/com.example.joker.sqltrial W/System.err:     at com.example.joker.sqltrial.MainActivity$1$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:74)
01-19 21:06:20.596 1514-1514/com.example.joker.sqltrial W/System.err:     at com.example.joker.sqltrial.MainActivity$1$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:70)
01-19 21:06:20.596 1514-1514/com.example.joker.sqltrial W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
01-19 21:06:20.596 1514-1514/com.example.joker.sqltrial W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
01-19 21:06:20.596 1514-1514/com.example.joker.sqltrial W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
01-19 21:06:20.596 1514-1514/com.example.joker.sqltrial W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-19 21:06:20.596 1514-1514/com.example.joker.sqltrial W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-19 21:06:20.596 1514-1514/com.example.joker.sqltrial W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-19 21:06:20.596 1514-1514/com.example.joker.sqltrial W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
01-19 21:06:20.596 1514-1514/com.example.joker.sqltrial W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 21:06:20.596 1514-1514/com.example.joker.sqltrial W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-19 21:06:20.596 1514-1514/com.example.joker.sqltrial W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
01-19 21:06:20.596 1514-1514/com.example.joker.sqltrial W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
01-19 21:06:20.596 1514-1514/com.example.joker.sqltrial W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-19 21:06:22.620 221-542/? W/genymotion_audio: out_write() limiting sleep time 43809 to 39909
```

Comment: `(MainActivity.java:74)` What is line 74 of MainActivity.java?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice
    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void urlSet(String URL){
    REGISTER_REQUEST_URL=URL;
}
```

By making this method and `REGISTER_REQUEST_URL` static, you are saying that **every** `PostRequest` object has the same URL. Since you want to change the URL for each request, neither this method nor the variable should be static. Instead, they should be a non-static member field and method.

This change will cause some other issues with your code. You will need to figure out how to set the URL on the correct `PostRequest` instance.

Comment: when i do change it to a non-static method i get an error stating "error:non-static method urlSet(String) cannot be referenced form a static context... after that i went back to the postRequest class and tried to change the REGISTER_REQUEST_URL to a non static String and i got an error at this line:
super (Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
with a red squiggly error underline underneath the URL part...does that mean this method requires a static URL? if so how would i be able to loop aroudn so that i can change it to variable?

Comment: @NishsBlemm Which line gives that error? Probably the call to `super()` in the `PostRequest` constructor, right? It seems to me that you should add another parameter for the URL.

Comment: super (Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
that is the line that gives me an error...i get an error specificlly where the URL is...im not sure what you mean by adding another paramater...im fairly new to java...ive only been coding for about a year now...

Comment: @NishsBlemm I suggest you read a tutorial about methods and constructors. This will explain what parameters are.

Comment: im sorry i did not properly word my question.i was wondering if i could have the option to change the parameters before the constructor is run... like a static variable..i understand how class inheritance works, and i understand that the super refers to the constructor of the superclass...what i am confused about is how/ or is it even possible..to have the option to change the static variable before the constructor. i understand that static variables are initialized before the constructor..but i would like to be able to call on to that class and change the URL based on what the user picks. ...

Comment: instead of having a URL initialized...i would like to have an option between 4-5 different URL's all based on what the user picks

Comment: @nishsblemm The URL should be non-static. Add a parameter to the PostRequest constructor for the URL then pass it on to super().

Comment: thank you, that worked! i was confused thinking that the StringRequest superclass required a static URL... noob learning in the process, thanks again!